# How to export the results of a MS Access query to a specific sheet of the excel

Tags: ms-access

I am new to MS access and VBA and need help.
what I do is export the results of the MS access Query in the Excel sheet manually. I am trying to automate this. So what I am trying to do is to create a VBA code in the Module of MS access where once I run the code, it will run the said query , then save the query results in the specific sheet of the excel file. Also it will delete the existing results that is stored in the sheet and will paste the new data.

I tried writing this code but its not working -

```
    Sub Test()

    Dim xlApp As Excel.Application
    Dim xlBook As Excel.Workbook
    Dim xlQuery As String
    Dim xlfile As String


        strDate = Format(Date, "yymmdd")

        Set xlApp = New Excel.Application
        xlApp.Visible = True
        'Open the Master Workbook Template
        Set xlBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open("C:\Testing\Template.xls", , False)

        xlQuery = "qry_1"
        xlfile = "C:\Testing\Template.xls"

    DoCmd.OpenQuery "qry_1"
    DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acExport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel8, xlQuery, xlfile, True, Worksheets("hello")

Set xlApp = Nothing
Set xlBook = Nothing
    End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

All you need is:

```
Dim xlQuery As String
Dim xlfile As String

xlQuery = "qry_1"
xlfile = "C:\Testing\Template.xls"

DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acExport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel8, xlQuery, xlfile, True, "hello$"
```

Comment: Thanks, but I am getting error as Table "hello$" already exists. Actually I have a excel template and i will just refresh this template everytime with the new Data. so I have the Excel file and all the Tabs are already named like "hello"

Comment: It sounds like you try to import the worksheet. There is no "table" hello in the workbook.